# Accessing Outer class attribute from an instance of an Inner class

Tags: java, nested-class

Given the following code:

```
public class Outer
{
   public final int n;
   public class Inner implements Comparable<Inner>
   {
      public int compareTo(Inner that) throws ClassCastException
      {
          if (Outer.this.n != Outer.that.n) // pseudo-code line
          {
               throw new ClassCastException("Only Inners with the same value of n are comparable");
//...
```

What can I swap out with my pseudo-code line so that I can compare the values of n for the two instances of the Inner class?

Trying the obvious solution (`n != that.n`) doesn't compile:

```
Outer.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable n
location: class Outer.Inner
                    if (n != that.n) // pseudo-code line
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated with an instance of its enclosing class and has direct access to that object's methods and fields. - [Java OO](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

You could write a getter method in the inner class, which returns `n` of the outer class.

Method on `Inner`:

```
public int getOuterN() { return n; }
```

Then compare using this method:

```
getOuterN() != that.getOuterN()
```

Comment: `n` is a public attribute of Outer, and not accessible as an attribute of `that`.  Trying this gives a "cannot find symbol" error

Comment: somebody copied my first answer ;) - does n!= that.n work after all?

Comment: I wound up going with the slightly more general `public Outer parent() { return Outer.this; }` so I could access all the members I needed to.